# Is there a way in pandas to groupby and then count unique where another column has a specified value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, unique

I have a pandas dataframe with numerous columns. For simplicity, let's say the columns are, 'country', 'time_bucket', 'category' and 'id'. The 'category' can be either 'staff' or 'student'.

```
import pandas as pd
    data = {'country':  ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B',],
            'time_bucket': ['8', '8', '8', '8', '9'],
            'category': ['staff', 'staff', 'student','student','staff'],
            'id': ['101', '172', '122', '142', '132'],
            }
        
        df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['country','time_bucket', 'category', 'id'])
df


country time_bucket category    id
0   A      8      staff        101
1   A      8      staff        172
2   A      8      student      122
3   B      8      student      142
4   B      9      staff        132
```

I want to find out the total number of staff and the total number of students in a country at a particular time interval and add these as new columns.

I can get the total number of people in a country at a particular time interval:

```
df['persons_count'] = df.groupby(['time_bucket','country'])['id'].transform('nunique')

country time_bucket category    id  persons_count
0   A      8         staff      101    3
1   A      8         staff      172    3
2   A      8         student    122    3
3   B      8         student    142    1
4   B      9         staff      132    1
```

However, I cannot work out how to take 'type' into account and add this in to my code.

I want something like this:

```
country time_bucket category    id  staff_count student_count
0   A     8          staff      101     2           1  
1   A     8          staff      172     2           1
2   A     8          student    122     2           1
3   B     8          student    142     0           1
4   B     9          staff      132     1           0
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

---

**Adding a new example which shows the need for unique 'id' count**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'country':  ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A','B', 'B',],
                'time_bucket': ['8', '8', '8', '8', '8','9'],
                'category': ['staff', 'staff', 'student','student','student','staff'],
                'id': ['101', '172', '122', '122','142', '132'],
                }
        
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['country','time_bucket', 'category', 'id'])
df

country time_bucket category    id
0   A     8         staff       101
1   A     8         staff       172
2   A     8         student     122
3   A     8         student     122
4   B     8         student     142
5   B     9         staff       132
```

I want something like this:

```
country time_bucket category    id  staff_count student_count
0   A     8          staff      101     2           1  
1   A     8          staff      172     2           1
2   A     8          student    122     2           1
3   A     8          student    122     2           1
4   B     8          student    142     0           1
5   B     9          staff      132     1           0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'country':  ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B',],
    'time_bucket': ['8', '8', '8', '8', '9'],
    'category': ['staff', 'staff', 'student','student','staff'],
    'id': ['101', '172', '122', '142', '132'],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['country','time_bucket', 'category', 'id'])


df['persons_count'] = df.groupby(['time_bucket','country', 'category'])['id'].transform('nunique')

df = df.pivot_table(index=['country','time_bucket','id'], columns='category',values='persons_count').fillna(0)
```

Output

```
                     category   staff   student
country time_bucket        id       
      A           8       101     2.0       0.0
                          122     0.0       1.0
                          172     2.0       0.0
      B           8       142     0.0       1.0
                  9       132     1.0       0.0
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris - this mostly worked on my problem once I joined the pivot back into the dataframe. The 'persons_count' column didn't count the total people that I needed so I used my original code for that, but otherwise, the pivot worked perfectly! I changed the index to just ['time_bucket','country'] and it did the job! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `groupby` operation with `apply`. The `apply` takes a function as an argument which will receive a sub dataframe for each grouping. Using the data you gave and grouping by [country, time_bucket] it would receive 3 rows for [A,8], 1 for [B,8] and 1 for [B,9]

To get the output you requested:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

data = {'country':  ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
        'time_bucket': ['8', '8', '8', '8', '9'],
        'category': ['staff', 'staff', 'student', 'student', 'staff'],
        'id': ['101', '172', '122', '142', '132'],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['country', 'time_bucket', 'category', 'id'])


def category_counter(row):
    counter = Counter(row.category.tolist())
    for k in ['staff', 'student']:
        row[k+'_count'] = counter[k]
    return row


df.groupby(['country', 'time_bucket']).apply(category_counter)
```

Output:

```
  country time_bucket category   id  staff_count  student_count
0       A           8    staff  101            2              1
1       A           8    staff  172            2              1
2       A           8  student  122            2              1
3       B           8  student  142            0              1
4       B           9    staff  132            1              0
```

An alternative which doesn't return duplicate data:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

data = {'country':  ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
        'time_bucket': ['8', '8', '8', '8', '9'],
        'category': ['staff', 'staff', 'student', 'student', 'staff'],
        'id': ['101', '172', '122', '142', '132'],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['country', 'time_bucket', 'category', 'id'])


def category_counter(row):
    counter = Counter(row.category.tolist())
    return_data = {}
    for k in ['staff', 'student']:
        return_data[k+'_count'] = counter[k]

    return pd.Series(return_data)


df.groupby(['country', 'time_bucket']).apply(category_counter)
```

Output:

```
                     staff_count  student_count
country time_bucket
A       8                      2              1
B       8                      0              1
        9                      1              0
```